# JavaScript function for adding up checkboxes from a form

Tags: javascript, html

My previous question got closed for a typo, although I'm not sure why as there were more problems in my logic. However, I have edited the loop and I still can not get it working. I need to add up multiple items and enter the answer into the text box, however I cant seem to see a problem.

JavaScript

```
<script>
"use strict";

const form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
const total = form.getElementById('total');
const checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]');
const cbamount = checkboxes.length;

 document.getElementsByName('event[]')[0].onclick = function() {
    totalPrice()
};

function totalPrice(){
    let totalPrice = 0;
    for (let i=0; i< cbamount; i++) {
       const box = checkboxes[i];
       if (box.checked) {
          totalPrice += box.dataset.price;
       }//if
}//for
}


document.getElementsByName("txtTotalPrice").value = totalprice;
```

HTML for the text box

```
<section id="checkCost">
        <h2>Total cost</h2>
        Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly="">
    </section>
```

HTML for the item (there are multiple)

```
<span class="eventTitle">Winter</span>
            <span class="eventStartDate">2020</span>
            <span class="eventEndDate">2020</span>
            <span class="catDesc">Fam</span>
            <span class="venueName">Disc</span>
            <span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
            <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="12" data-price="0.00">
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: why is `document.getElementsByName("txtTotalPrice").value = totalprice;` outside of your function?

Comment: `totalPrice += box.dataset.price;` you are adding a string to a number

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('event[]')[0].onclick = ...` you are binding to one checkbox

Comment: ` value="12" data-price="0.00"` where is the logic ??

Answer (score 0):

there were a number of errors involving case.

you were using `form.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementById`

same with `form.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.querySelectorAll`

also, you are using `getElementsByName` which returns an array, so return to only [0].

further: you will likely find an issue with the return being a string, and additional clicks will append to that string rather than adding as numbers.

also: you had `document.getElementsByName("txtTotalPrice").value = totalprice;`[SIC] outside of the function bracket so it was not being called at the right time.

the example works with minimal fixes though.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
const total = document.getElementById('total');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]');
const cbamount = checkboxes.length;

document.getElementsByName('event[]')[0].onclick = function() {
  totalPrice()
};



function totalPrice() {
  let totalprice = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < cbamount; i++) {
    const box = checkboxes[i];
    if (box.checked) {
      totalprice += box.dataset.price;
    } //if
  } //for

  document.getElementsByName("txtTotalPrice")[0].value = totalprice;
}
```

```html
<section id="checkCost">
  <h2>Total cost</h2>
  Total <input type="text" name="txtTotalPrice" size="10" value="-_-">
</section>

<span class="eventTitle">Winter</span>
<span class="eventStartDate">2020</span>
<span class="eventEndDate">2020</span>
<span class="catDesc">Fam</span>
<span class="venueName">Disc</span>
<span class="eventPrice">0.00</span>
<span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="12" data-price="0.00">
```

Comment: @epascarello how wrong?  I repaired the code he posted.  Had he intended me to add prices from multiple boxes he would have provided them.

Comment: My second comment under the OPs post.

Comment: @epascarello that line is inside of the function in my version.

Comment: @epascarello I made mention of the `string` issue.  That is not the only issue he will have as he tries to make this workable.  I did not presume to fix all his problems, just the ones he posted.

Comment: @epascarello it is not about difficulty, but choice.  He may prefer to use Number(), or parseFloat() or the unary`+`  

I fixed the case issues, and the functional issues.  Someone else did a full-on handholding, so it's ok.   note: neither answer was upvoted lol

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementById()` only works when called from `document`, you can't use it from another selection like you had - `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` *do* work however, so I've used those

`document.getElementsByName('event[]')[0]` was only selecting the first input, because of `[0]` - getElementsByName returns a NodeList of elements, which is similar to an Array. I've just used the `checkboxes` selection you had already defined, as it targeting the same elements

`document.getElementsByName("txtTotalPrice").value = totalprice` was outside of the function it should have been called in, and so wasn't getting any value passsed to it

Also, it feels redundant that your inputs have a value of 0, but data-price set to your values; is there a reason you can't just use the value attribute here?

I've added a few extra input boxes, and changed the selector for your `total` input, just to better test this. Feel free to tell me if something isn't right with those

```js
const form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
const total = document.getElementById('total');

const checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]');

checkboxes.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('click', totalPrice);
});

function totalPrice() {
  let totalCost = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    const box = checkboxes[i];
    if (box.checked) {
      totalCost += parseFloat(box.dataset.price);
    }
  }
  
  /* Added a cleaner way to find totalCost, if wanted
  let totalCost = [...checkboxes].reduce((total, box) => {
    return box.checked ? total += parseFloat(box.dataset.price) : total;
  }, 0);
  */  
  
  total.value = totalCost;
}
```

```html
<section id="checkCost">
  <h2>Total cost</h2>
  Total: <input id="total" type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly>
</section>

<form id="bookingForm">
  <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="1.00" data-price="1.00"></span>
  <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="3.50" data-price="3.50"></span>
  <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="5.25" data-price="5.25"></span>
</form>
```